# How to insert dynamic value on url cypress

Tags: cypress

Hi there I am new to cypress and learning,

My data is dynamic and changes every second. Imagine a table with Column city and city incharge. The city incharge is dynamic and changes every minute.

This is clickable and holds a link.  This particular part changes more frequently and I want to check if the href holds correct value.

```html
<a href="/City/incharge/Mr.A" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Mr.A">
</a>
```

I tried to store the value in a variable but then not sure how to add it to the url to see if it is correct.

For example I tried code in cypress like this,

```
it('Check click function on Transactionhash', () => {
    cy.get('td').eq(1).then(($incharge) => {
    var name = $incharge.text(); // Storing the dynamic value to a variable
    cy.get('td').eq(1).click()
    cy.url().should('eq','https://worldmap.com/city/'name')
});
```

This 'name' part on the above url should have the dynamic value. In our case Mr.A which might change in future to anything.

Can somebody please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample it should be something like this:

```
it('Check click function on Transactionhash', () => {
  let name = ''
  cy.get('td').eq(1)
    .then(incharge => {
      name = incharge.text()
      cy.get('td')
        .eq(1)
        .click()
      cy.url()
        .should('eq',`https://worldmap.com/city/${name}`)
  })
})
```

Note the usage of backticks (`) in the should() function

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :D When I am able to achieve partly what I want, the name part contains `\n Mr.A \n'. I assume we are supposed to use something like trim function can you please help me further?

Comment: Update: I used another variable trimmedname = name.trim() and used the ${trimedname} to check which worked perfectly. But the problem is the text is so long that they actually display it in a short version and the full text is available in the 'data-original-title'. Is it possible to store the value of data-original-title? If I use cy.get('td').eq(1) the shorthand version gets stored. Thanks for your help